# SQL Query to Get Sum of Program Values using Calculations and Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I asked a question similar to this earlier however I don't think I gave enough info for what I am trying to do. 
I have the following Tables.

```
Program Table - 
        prog_ID, 
        prog_Name

Unit Table - 
        unit_ID, 
        unit_name, 
        prog_ID
        max_beds
        max_budgeted-beds
        max_unbudgeted-beds
        max_escalation-beds

Import_Data Table - 
        bed_ID, 
        unit_ID
        ...other unrelated data


Bed Table - 
        bed_ID, 
        bed_type_ID

Bed Type Table - 
        bed_type_ID, 
        bed_type
```

I am trying to determine the following as column headers in my output:

Occupied Beds

```
--Total Occupied Beds (SUM of Beds of type 'Regular' in Import Table)
(SUM(CASE WHEN Bed_Type.bed_type_description = 'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) As 'Total Occupied'
```

Budgeted Beds

```
--OCCUPIED BUDGETED BEDS (IF # of 'Regular' beds for the Program is < max_budgeted_beds than this is the Sum of the 'Regular' beds for the program, If its > than the Budgeted than this value = max_budgeted_beds for the program)

(SUM WHEN < MAX_BUDGETED),(CASE WHEN (SUM (CASE WHEN Bed_Type.bed_type_description =     'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) < UNIT.unit_beds_max_budgeted THEN (SUM (CASE WHEN Bed_Type.bed_type_description = 'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE Unit.unit_beds_max_budgeted END) AS 'Occupied Budgeted Beds'
```

Unbudgeted Beds

```
--OCCUPIED UNBUDGETED BEDS (IF # of 'Regular' beds for the Program is < max_budgeted_beds than this is 0, If its > than the Budgeted than this value = max_budgeted_beds + max_unbudgeted_beds - # of 'Regular' beds for the program)
    , (CASE WHEN (SUM (CASE WHEN Bed_Type.bed_type_description = 'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > UNIT.unit_beds_max_budgeted THEN Unit.unit_beds_max_unbudgeted + Unit.unit_beds_max_budgeted - (SUM (CASE WHEN Bed_Type.bed_type_description = 'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Occupied Unbudgeted Beds'
```

I get an error in here surrounding the reference to 'Unit.unit_beds_max_budgeted' and I'm not sure why.  I am using this logic in a different query that works but that output is giving me each Unit like this:

```
Program  Unit  Occupied_Beds   Budgeted_Beds   Unbudgeted_Beds
---------------------------------------------------------------
MED      A2    44              42              2
MED      A3    34              32              2
CCC      B2    44              42              2
CCC      B3    34              32              2
```

However the output I am trying for is to have MED, and CCC, as one row with the values rolled up (and exclude the Unit Name).

Any help is greatly appreciated, wracking my brain with this and I feel it should be really easy but I can't get it. Am I missing a necessary field to make the link?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have an outer aggregate function outside the CASE statement for unbudgeted beds.   You must either group by that column, or aggregate it.    Also, what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: There error I'm getting is this:  Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Column 'Unit.unit_beds_max_budgeted' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Column 'Unit.unit_beds_max_budgeted' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by 'aggregate it'

Comment: aggregate = a count ... etc aggregate functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is telling you you need to aggregate your unbudgeted beds column.   It's not enough that there are aggregates inside the CASE statement.   You need an outer aggregate function.

If you re-write it like this, the error should be fixed:

```
--OCCUPIED UNBUDGETED BEDS (IF # of 'Regular' beds for the Program is < max_budgeted_beds than this is 0, If its > than the Budgeted than this value = max_budgeted_beds + max_unbudgeted_beds - # of 'Regular' beds for the program)
    , SUM(
       CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN Bed_Type.bed_type_description = 'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > UNIT.unit_beds_max_budgeted 
              THEN Unit.unit_beds_max_unbudgeted + Unit.unit_beds_max_budgeted - (SUM (CASE WHEN Bed_Type.bed_type_description = 'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
            ELSE 0 END
       ) AS 'Occupied Unbudgeted Beds'
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this.  It is throwing a new error now, saying:    Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.  Is there a way to break this up somehow? The logic is right.

Comment: I think you're going to need to break this up with a CTE.   You can simply remove the SUM in the THEN clause, but you'll need to do the SUM for the comparison to UNIT.unit_beds_max_budgeted in a CTE or derived table.   It can't be performed inside this aggregation.

Comment: Ok. This is what I started to do but I wondered if it was the wrong way to go.  What I have is a Procedure that gives me These Calculations for Each Unit and dumps it into a new Table.  Then a second Procedure that takes this table and sums based on the Program.  Does that sound smart?  I apologize, I know I've done stuff like this but I'm just getting back into SQL work.

Comment: Well using a separate stored procedure for it might be overkill, unless there are other places where you might call that same stored procedure.  However, any solution that gets the correct results and is fast enough for your needs is smart enough.

Comment: OH Sorry, no I have one stored procedure.  Just that it is broken into 2 seperate queries. One to do the calculations and build the new Results Table, then the second part rolls up the data by Program.  Will that work, if the table gets updated by the first half of the procedure and then referenced for the second part?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I was suggesting.  You're using a table instead of a CTE, but the logic is the same.